# How can I redirect a user to the product if the user lands on an image popup in Magento?

Tags: image, magento, popup, product, back

The problem is that from time to time people enter the site through the image pop-up page after a search in Google, and the pop-up only has the functions to go to next image, previous image and close window. So it doesn't present the customer with the possibility to see the product page corresponding to the image pop-up thus resulting in bounce.

I would like to add a go to product page button as well, but I don't know how.

Comment: can you please be more specific

Answer (score 0):

There are several options. One you can change magento 'view large' image window with some lightbox plugin that would create popup on the page and not new browser window. This would be not indexed by google. Then you can create rewrite from popup addresses to homepage (or product page). 
If you want to keep the current way of displaying large images then the only way is to check the referer header and if it is not from your shop redirect customer to the page.

Comment: Thanks. Went for the lightbox solution and now works fine. Sorry for the late reply.